# Вынести в метод

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Как можно корректно вынести в метод данный тест:

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.textView), withHint(R.string.ui_common_email)))
            .perform(replaceText(AcceptanceConstants.TEST_NAME), closeSoftKeyboard())
```

Под корректно имеется в виду что аргументы данного теста будут меняться, следовательно мне придётся использовать каждый раз разные аргументы в созданном методе.

Пробую примерно следующим образом:

```
 fun someMethod(String id, String text, String textar) {
    onView(allOf(withId(R.id.textView), withHint(AcceptanceConstants.FULL_NAME)))
            .perform(replaceText(AcceptanceConstants.TEST_NAME), closeSoftKeyboard())
}
```

и потом вызывать его:

```
someMethod(сюда параметры уже через запятую)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так если вы собираетесь потом менять параметры, то и соответственно в методе передавайте те значения которые хотите менять. Вижу Вы используете `fun` а значит это kotlin, а не java.

Ну а поподробней будет выглядить примерно так:

```
fun updateValidationViewText(id: String, hint: String, newText: String) {
    Espresso.onView(Matchers.allOf(ViewMatchers.withId(id), ViewMatchers.withHint(hint)))
            .perform(ViewActions.replaceText(newText), ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard())
}
```

И уже после этого вызываете свой метод, где Вам нужно, с задаваемыми Вами параметрами.

Answer (score 0):

Можно передавать ссылку на активити.

Например:

```
private class SomeHelper {
    public void someMethod(Activity myActivity, String id, String text, String textar) {
        myActivity.onView(allOf(withId(R.id.textView), withHint(AcceptanceConstants.FULL_NAME)))
                .perform(replaceText(AcceptanceConstants.TEST_NAME), closeSoftKeyboard())
    }
  }
```